# Error #90: Another process has updated 'BAccount' record. Your changes will be lost

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update a BAccount record twice but on the second time it throws the above exception.

I also see PXLockViolationException when I drill down in the exception.  I so guessing there some sort transaction thing going on.

Basically Im adding a Customer record using the CustomerMaint graph

Saving the record using graph.Actions.Save()

Then later on in the same process I am adding the vendor record for the same customer (Baccount) using the VendorMaint graph which when I persist the change it throws that error.

Any help would be appreciated.

cheers

Comment: please give your code for more understanding.

Comment: what do you mean by "adding the vendor record for the same customer " . If you are trying to add the vendor with same ID as of customer, it is not possible i think. As acumatica gives an error
"This ID is already used for another Vendor or Customer record."

Comment: Customer and Vendor share the same BAccount record in the database.  So the BAccount record already exists im just updating it and adding a vendor record.  My code works it just doesnt work when I update the customer side and then update the vendor side in the same process

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the fact that you try to persist an outdated DAC. The reason is that you have multiple instances of the same DAC in memory. Once you persist the updated instance you will get an exception if you try to persist the outdated one. To understand why you are playing with multiple instance, we need to understand the relation between the different classes you are using.

The classes AR.Customer and AP.Vendor inherit both directly from CR.BAccount.

Declaration of Customer:

```
public partial class Customer : BAccount, PX.SM.IIncludable
```

Declaration of Vendor

```
public partial class Vendor : CR.BAccount, PX.SM.IIncludable
```

The different possible states for CR.BAccount are

- Prospect
- Customer
- Vendor
- Customer and Vendor (Combined)

To convert from Prospect to Vendor or from Customer or Vendor, please refer to the function ConvertToVendor in BusinessAccountMaint:

```
public PXAction<BAccount> converToVendor;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.ConvertToVendor, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Process)]
public virtual IEnumerable ConverToVendor(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    BAccount bacct = this.BAccount.Current;
    if (bacct != null && (bacct.Type == BAccountType.ProspectType || bacct.Type == BAccountType.CustomerType))
    {
        Save.Press();
        AP.VendorMaint editingBO = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AP.VendorMaint>();
        AP.VendorR vendor = (AP.VendorR)editingBO.BAccount.Cache.Extend<BAccount>(bacct);
        editingBO.BAccount.Current = vendor;
        vendor.Type = (bacct.Type == BAccountType.ProspectType) ? BAccountType.VendorType : BAccountType.CombinedType;
        LocationExtAddress defLocation = editingBO.DefLocation.Select();
        editingBO.DefLocation.Cache.RaiseRowSelected(defLocation);
        string locationType = (bacct.Type == BAccountType.ProspectType) ? LocTypeList.VendorLoc : LocTypeList.CombinedLoc;
        editingBO.InitVendorLocation(defLocation, locationType);
        defLocation = editingBO.DefLocation.Update(defLocation);
        foreach (Location iLoc in editingBO.IntLocations.Select())
        {
            if (iLoc.LocationID != defLocation.LocationID)
            {
                editingBO.InitVendorLocation(iLoc, locationType);
                editingBO.IntLocations.Update(iLoc);
            }
        }
        editingBO.Answers.CopyAttributes(vendor, bacct);
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(editingBO, Messages.EditVendor);
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

To call ConverToCustomer and ConverToVendor on the same process, you need to keep the same instance of the BAccount class:

```
    public PXAction<BAccount> converToCustomerThenVendor;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Convert To Customer Then Vendor No Redirection", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Process)]
    public virtual IEnumerable ConverToCustomerThenVendor(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        //Convert to Customer
        try
        {
            Base.converToCustomer.Press();
        }
        catch (PXRedirectRequiredException ex)
        {
            var customerGraph = ex.Graph as CustomerMaint;
            //Add your own extended logic here. 


            //Save the new Customer to the database
            customerGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            //Set the current instance of BAccount as the one you just saved in the customer graph
            Base.BAccount.Current = customerGraph.BAccount.Current;
        }

        //Convert to vendor
        try
        {
            Base.converToVendor.Press();
        }
        catch(PXRedirectRequiredException ex)
        {
            var vendorGraph = ex.Graph as VendorMaint;
            //Add your own extended logic here. 


            //Save the new Vendor to the database
            vendorGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            //Set the current instance of BAccount as the one you just saved in the vendor graph
            Base.BAccount.Current = vendorGraph.BAccount.Current;
        }

        //Refresh the page with the new data
        Base.Actions.PressCancel();
        return adapter.Get();

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks yea that make sense.  I am trying to add a combined type record

When I add it is in a process outside of the customer screen.  How can access those actions converToVendor through my instance of the customerMaint graph?

Comment: There is a similar action in the CustomerMaint called ExtendToVendor/extendToVendor

Answer (score 0):

After you add the customer,

1. clear the graph,
2. Load the customer record to the graph by setting the current
3. Then add other details
4. Save